# Rooting: Sony ST23i USB Debugging mode problems

Tags: android, root, sony, sony-xperia, usb-debugging

So I want to root my Sony Xperia Miro to get Cyanogenmod which has proposed that it can get my phone to Android Kitkat, but when I try and root it with OneClickRoot it doesn't recognise that my phone is on USB Debugging Mode with it on Mass Storage Mode.

I'm on a Windows 7 64bit Lenovo laptop

Answer (score 0):

Install drivers for your phone by installing SOny PC companion, istall adb adb and fastboot from this link

https://github.com/koush/UniversalAdbDriver

Den use any tool you wish , best tool is

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1886460